# The bash shell uses the read loop to read the assignment in the text, the space separator problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The content of the file.txt text is as follows

```
domain_wisgene.com  keyword谷歌搜索 - This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome    title谷歌搜索 - Google,Search,is,Awesome
```

code show as below

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' now_list_url now_list_keyword now_list_title; do
  # Do something with the variables here
    
echo "domain_name：${now_list_url}"
echo "Key words：${now_list_keyword}"
echo "title：${now_list_title}"

done <file.txt
```

**result**

```
#domain
domain_name：domain_wisgene.com
#keywords
Key words：keyword谷歌搜索
#title
title：- This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome   title谷歌搜索 - Google,Search,is,Awesome
```

**wrong result**

```
#domain
domain_name：domain_wisgene.com
#keywrods
Key words：keyword谷歌搜索 - This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome
#title
title：- This,is,keyword,google,search,awesometitle    谷歌搜索 - Google,Search,is,Awesome
```

**I want the correct result**

```
#domain
domain_name：domain_wisgene.com
#keywords
Key words：keyword谷歌搜索 - This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome
#title
title：title谷歌搜索 - Google,Search,is,Awesome"
```

Looking for help How do I solve this complicated delimiter problem, I want to use the default space as the delimiter, but there are also spaces in the variable value characters, how do I deal with the " - " in the variable without delimiting?

Example: This is one of the lines in file.txt

```
domain_wisgene.com keyword Google Search - This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome title Google Search - Google,Search,is,Awesome
```

Pass variable 1 variable 2 variable 3

```
Variable 1 = domain_wisgene.com
Variable 2 = keyword google search - This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome
Variable 3 = title Google Search - Google,Search,is,Awesome`
```

**I want the correct result**

```
domain_name：domain_wisgene.com
Key words：keyword谷歌搜索 - This,is,keyword,google,search,awesome
title：title谷歌搜索 - Google,Search,is,Awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter needs are too complex for read. You can maybe use sed to separate the fields like so:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' now_list_url now_list_keyword now_list_title < <(sed -E 's/^(<domain-regex>)\s+(<keywords-regex>)\s+(<title-regex>)$/\1\n\2\n\3/g' file.txt)
```

Explanation:

- sed replaces \1, \2, and \3 with the text that 1st, 2nd, and 3rd parentheses-wrapped expressions captured.
- I capture the 3 variables then write them again with a newline delimiter. Now they are in a format suitable for read. You can replace the newline with whatever delimiter you know won't be in the input (personally I am fond of `\x1F`, the Unit Separator).
- \s is shorthand for any whitespace character.
- You will have to fill in the `<regex>`s yourself as I don't know what the general rule is that you want.

Comment: Hello, I used your method and it still doesn't work

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what exactly happened? Please elaborate further.

Comment: Can you write a complete example in code? Because tried using your way, there is no output

Comment: @stla If you want help you'll have to write the code you tried and the output you got. I gave you a snippet that shows how to solve your specific problem, but you still need to know how to plug it into your script. Particularly I ignored the while loop you have there. Or maybe your regex's are wrong, I won't be able to tell if you don't show what you tried. It's also possible that sed doesn't handle those Chinese (?) characters in your input so well. If that's the case, I don't know what you can do.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, I will send the code in the form of answering questions, you can take a look

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, I will send the code in the form of answering questions, you can take a look

Comment: You can see my whole problem, I save all the required values ​​in a text
Then I use while to read it and assign to the corresponding variable, but there are spaces! And read is very difficult to deal with spaces, and if there are spaces, it will be staged